# Appium ANDROID_HOME env variable issues

Tags: appium

Happy new year all, I'd gratefully appreciate if someone could help or shed some light into this issue.

I've just set up appium 1.7.2 server on MAC OS High Sierra v 10.13.2, running appium through below command.
`appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 --log-level=debug`

---

**Below is my .bash_profile**

```
n.nadarajah@EGHJ-MACRDV01 ~ $ cat ~/.bash_profile
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/n.nadarajah/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
ANDROID_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/tools
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}:$JAVA_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME:
$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$ANDROID_TOOLS"
export PATH
```

---

**Echoing $ANDRIOD_HOME env variable**

```
n.nadarajah@EGHJ-MACRDV01 ~ $ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/n.nadarajah/Library/Android/sdk
```

---

**Below are the Appium logs on test execution.**

```
n.nadarajah@EGHJ-MACRDV01 ~ $ appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 --log-l . 
level=debug
info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV 
ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1"}
info: Console LogLevel: debug
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":
{"platformName":"Android"},"firstMatch":
[{}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"deviceName":"Android 
Emulator","app":"/Users/n.nadarajah/sites/Resilient-
QA/EndToEndTesting/apks/app-
debug.apk","platformName":"Android","automationName":"appium",
"appPackage":"com.resilientplc.smartnumbers.debug"}}
info: Client User-Agent string: Python http auth
info: [debug] No appActivity desired capability or server param. 
Parsing from apk.
info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: 
/Users/n.nadarajah/sites/Resilient-QA/EndToEndTesting
/apks/app-debug.apk
info: [debug] Creating new appium session 
a5cfbee9-bcd6-41af-a90c-0389ab244d2c
info: Starting android appium
info: [debug] Getting Java version
info: Java version is: 1.8.0_151
info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
warn: The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set to the Android 
SDK root directory path. 
ANDROID_HOME is required for compatibility with SDK 23+. 
Checking along PATH for adb.
info: [debug] executing cmd: which adb
info: [debug] Using adb from /Users/n.nadarajah/
Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
info: [debug] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
warn: The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set to the Android 
SDK root directory path. 
ANDROID_HOME is required for compatibility with SDK 23+. 
Checking along PATH for aapt.
info: [debug] executing cmd: which aapt
error: Problem parsing package and activity from manifest: Error: Could 
not find aapt. Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment 
variable with the Android SDK root directory path.
info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not 
find aapt. Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable 
with the Android SDK root directory path.
info: [debug] Error: Could not find aapt. 
Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the 
Android SDK root directory path.at ADB.<anonymous> 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium
/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/adb.js:126:12)
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:279:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:363:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:568:12)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":
{"message":"A new session could not be created. 
(Original error: Could not find aapt. Please set the ANDROID_HOME 
environment variable with the Android SDK root 
directory path.)","origValue":"Could not find aapt. Please set the 
ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the 
Android SDK root directory path."},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 164.317 ms - 344
```

---

**Questions:**
1. Why does appium cannot see the system environment variable?

I've tried appium server versions 1.7.2 & 1.7.1 & 1.6.2 & 1.4.16 the symptoms were the same.
Could someone help me out with this please.

Thanks
Niro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got to the bottom of this issue,
turns out I've missed another android env variable.

In the above case I've missed **ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS**

At the point of writing this, below are the list of Env variables required for appium.

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/n.nadarajah/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/
Contents/Home/bin
ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
ANDROID_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/tools
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/27.0.3
```

Append all the above env variables to $PATH

Answer (score 1):

works for me in Mojave.

After editing `~/.bash_<profile or rc>` I use:

```
source ~/.bash_<profile or rc>
```

It not only loads the new variables values, as reports any error on file as well.

Answer (score 0):

here is the workin list of environment variables:

> export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
>
> export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/:$PATH
>   export
>   PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/:$PATH
>   export
>   PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/:$PATH export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH
>
> launchctl setenv ANDROID_HOME /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk

works on highSierra, of course, tweak Your paths...

Comment: Hi, @Kovacic trying to place your code in MacOs High Sierra 10.13.4 version it is not working and saying the "Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable".
But it is working in MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3 version device. Where i did the mistake.

Comment: be sure that this is Your path "/Users/XXXXXXX/Library/Android/sdk", or type in console "which android" and You replace /android with "/sdk", and You should be ok

Comment: Getting this output when run "which android" o/p:- is /Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/tools//android how can i edit the output path.

Comment: Hi, @Kovacic had made changes what you said but no luck. Is there any version defect.

Answer (score 0):

here I have installed android studio in default path.

First Set Android home: create a new System Variable

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Add bellow three path in path system variables

```
C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
```