# Appium always got error JAVA_HOME & ANDROID_HOME

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

[image: Screenshot appium and appium-doctor condition]

Step what I've done:

- Set JAVA_HOME & ANDROID_HOME in source ~/.bash_profile
- Restart my laptop
- Even reinstall appium

Stuck with this error attached.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have android studio installed ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48205606/5105390 ?

Or you can click 'Edit Configurations' on start of Appium ,and set variables there?

Answer (score 0):

Facing this same issue some time back, I entered JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME in edit configurations (on starting appium) and restarted the appium. It worked fine.

`ANDROID_HOME - /Users/{{user_name}}/Library/android/sdk

JAVA_HOME - /usr/bin/java`